# Excepción con animateCamera Google Map Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter

Como pueden apreciar en la pantalla principal estoy usando BottomNavigationBar, cuando navego a la Pagina Marcaje o Salida y vuelvo a la Pagina Ubicación(mapa) y presionó el botón de ubicación me muestra una excepción adjunto la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esta excepción se manifiesta cuando realizo la navegación como mencione hace un momento, pero cuando NO navego a las otras paginas funciona bien, sin problemas.**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   key: scaffoldkey,
   body: BlocBuilder<UbicacionBloc, UbicacionState>(
    builder: ( context , state) =>_crearGoogleMapa(context, state )
  ),
  floatingActionButton: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      BtnUbicacion(),
      BtnSeguirUbicacion(),
      _crearBotonFlotante(context),
     ],
    ),
   );
  }


Widget _crearGoogleMapa(BuildContext context, UbicacionState state){

if(!state.existeUbicacion) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

final mapaBloc = BlocProvider.of<MapaBloc>(context);
mapaBloc.add(OnNuevaUbicacion(state.ubicacion));

final cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(
  target: state.ubicacion,
  zoom: 15.0
);
_iniciarEventoGeoValla(context);

return GoogleMap(
  initialCameraPosition:cameraPosition,
  myLocationEnabled: true,
  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
  zoomControlsEnabled: false, 
  mapType: _tipoMapa,
  markers: Set.from(mapaBloc.state.markers),
  circles: Set.from(mapaBloc.state.circulos),
  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
    context.bloc<MapaBloc>().initMapa(controller);
  },
 );
}

class BtnUbicacion extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final mapaBloc = context.bloc<MapaBloc>();
final ubicacionBloc = context.bloc<UbicacionBloc>();  

return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
  child: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
    maxRadius: 25,
    child: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.my_location, color: Colors.black87), 
      onPressed: (){

        final destino = ubicacionBloc.state.ubicacion;  
        mapaBloc.moverCamara(destino);
       }
      ),
    ),
   );
  }
 }
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar o dar una opinión le agradecería mucho.

Comment: hola, sigues con el error? puedes dar más detalles?

Comment: hola Diego, gracias por tu respuesta, solucione mi error mirando unos de tus videos, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución para mi error, como estoy usando BottomNavigationBar y tengo 3 paginas
que cuando navego a una de ellas lo que hacia mi función era abrir la pagina y reemplazar por la anterior, esto me provoco el error y para solucionar estoy usando IndexedStack ya con esto me carga las 3 paginas y navego sin problemas.

espero ayude mi respuesta para otra persona.

```
 body: IndexedStack(
    index: pagina,
    children: [
      DetalleSalidaPage(),
      MapaPage(),
      MarcajePage()
    ],
  ),
```